# cross-compile Jansson C library for iOS

Tags: c++, c, gcc, cross-compiling, llvm-gcc

I am trying to cross compile [Jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/) for iOS (armv7) from my machine (x86_64). I have learned that with xcode 5, apple has removed llvm-gcc and thus, `armv7-apple-darwin-gcc` can't be found. The result lib is compiled for x86_64 instead.

This is my current configuration:

```
./configure --prefix=/resultdir --host=armv7-apple-darwin --target=armv7-apple-darwin
```

I saw multiple posts of people saying they have jansson compiled for arm architecture so I know its possible. Just can't seem to be able to do it.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have an older iPhoneOS 5.0 SDK installed on my system. I am sure that you can work with a newer version too. The following script successfully compiled Jansson for me:

```
export CC="/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang"
export CPP="clang -E"

export SDKPATH="/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk"
export CFLAGS="-arch armv7 -isysroot ${SDKPATH} -miphoneos-version-min=5.0"

export LDFLAGS="-isysroot ${SDKPATH}"

./configure --host=arm-apple-darwin10

make
```

The result is a library that I did not test, but `file` returns an arm architecture library:

```
$ file src/.libs/libjansson.4.dylib
src/.libs/libjansson.4.dylib: Mach-O dynamically linked shared library arm
```

Adjust `SDKPATH` and `-miphoneos-version-min=5.0` appropriately for the SDK that you have installed.